# Why polynoimal defined on endomorphism is in $L(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $L(V)={f:V\to V|}$ $f$ is linear map

$h=a_0+a_1x+..+a_nx^n$

the value of polynomial $h(x)$ on $f\in L(V)$ is defined like this

$h(f)=a_01_V+a_1f+a_2f^2+...+a_nf^n$

where $f^n=f\circ f^{n-1}$

now book says it's clear that $h(f) \in L(V)$.Can you explain why?

We should check that $h(f)$ is linear map from $V\to V$

should check that $h(f+g)=h(f)+h(g)$ and $h(cf)=ch(f)$

$h(f+g)=a_01_V+a_1(f+g)+..+a_n(f+g)^n$

$h(f)=a_01_V+a_1(f)+..+a_n(f)^n$

$h(g)=a_01_V+a_1(g)+..+a_n(g)^n$

from here I don't know how to continue.

EDIT.

$f\circ f(v_1+v_2)=f(f(v_1)+f(v_2))=f(f(v_1))+f(f(v_2))=f^2(v_1)+f^2(v_2)$

Comment: No, in order to prove that $h(f)$ is a linear map, you need to prove that $h(f)(v_1+v_2) = h(f)(v_1)+h(f)(v_1)$ and that $h(f)(cv) = ch(f)(v)$.

Comment: @azif00 Ok then how to prove that $f^n(v_1+v_2)=f^n(v_1)+f^n(v_2)$

Comment: Try with $n=2$. For general $n$ use induction.

Comment: @azif00 Thanks I edited is it right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. More generally, if $U, V, W$ are three vector spaces and $F : U \to V$ and $G : V \to W$ are linear maps, then $G \circ F : U \to W$ is also a linear map. Prove this, and the fact that $f^n$ is linear for all $n$ follows immediately by induction.